# Decidability of Frankl's union-closed sets conjecture

Tags: lo.logic, soft-question

Is it conceivable that [Frankl's union closed sets conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union-closed_sets_conjecture) is undecidable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, or is this quite implausible, perhaps due to the "finitistic" nature of the statement, or for some other reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The statement has [complexity $\Pi^0_1$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy), which means that it has a
single universal quantifier, quantifying over the possible
union-closed sets, and then making a simple assertion about those
objects.

Although this is a very simple level of complexity, it is the same
complexity as consistency assertions, and these admit of a robust
independence phenomenon. For example, even ZFC, if consistent,
admits of independent statements of this level of complexity, such as the statement Con(ZFC), which asserts that ZFC is consistent.

Meanwhile, if we can prove in ZFC (or some other theory) that the
union-closed set conjecture was independent of PA, then it would
follow that the statement was true in the standard model. The
reason is that if a $\Pi^0_1$ statement is independent of PA, then
it can admit of no standard counterexample, since PA would prove
that this was a counterexample. So, the situation is that if we
can prove in ZFC that the union-closed set conjecture is
independent of PA, then we would be able to prove in ZFC that it
is true.

Comment: Let me attach [this post of yours](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27670/independence-of-pa-implies-independence-of-pa-union-all-true-pi-1-statements/27677#27677) as an explanation for the last paragraph. I think the same argument used in the last paragraph can be used to show, instead of PA, if it is provably independent of ZFC, then it can proven to be true in ZFC+Con(ZFC), right?

Comment: Thanks for the link! But your remark isn't quite right, because in general, it depends on the theory that you used to prove the independence. For example, the $\Pi^0_1$ statement Con(ZFC+$\exists$inaccessible cardinal) is provably independent of ZFC in some strong large cardinal theories, but it is not provably true in ZFC+Con(ZFC).

Comment: I see, we might have to throw in the theory we prove the independence in. In any case, I think the point I was trying to make is that if we can prove consistency of a $\Pi^0_1$ sentence in some theory, then we can prove it to be true after assuming that that theories in which and from which independence is proven "sufficiently make sense".

Comment: Yes, I agree with that.